# Connect from Azure to an on-premise fileshare

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-functions, azure-stack, app-service-environment

From an Azure Function I need to read files on an on-premise Windows file-share. I have network access to the file server **but how do I authenticate**?

My Azure Function is running in an Isolated App Service Environment in Azure connected to a VNet that is peered to the on-premise corporate network though an express route.

Side note: I will get the same issue with Azure Functions running on Azure Stack Hub, but I guess the solution will be the same.

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I found, that there are libraries that talks directly to SMB servers. One of them is [SMBLibrary](https://github.com/TalAloni/SMBLibrary). I never implement a prof of concept.